# Using jquery mobile in IBM Worklight for WIndows Phone 8

Tags: jquery-mobile, windows-phone-8, ibm-mobilefirst

I have developed an application using jquery mobile 1.1.0. It works in Android and iOS environments. But I was not the same lucky when I tried to deploy the same application in Windows phone 8...The user interface is not shown...Is there any kind of incompatibility between windows phone 8 and jquery mobile?

Comment: what error message u got ?

Comment: I didn't get any error message...It doesn't show the application, just a white screen

Comment: can u show us some code what you have done here that possible lead to this problem?

Comment: There has to be some error. Look in the Output view in Visual Studio

Comment: Have you deployed it also on Windows 8.1? i had the same problem on this platform but never tried on Windows Phone 8.

Comment: Ok I got the error...Im loading different HTMLs in the same page using  $('id').load(page.html); and for some reason it is not working using jquery mobile 1.1.0 and windows phone 8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the sample project for multi-pages application as provided by IBM Worklight: http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/docs/v610/BuildingMultiPageApplicationProject.zip

The project contains special handling for Windows Phone 8, as it treats file location differently than other environments (such as Android and iOS).