# AngularJS Routes not working on Windows Phone 8 (using Worklight)

Tags: angularjs, windows-phone-8, ibm-mobilefirst

I am developing a Hybrid App for iOS,Android,BB and Windows using IBM Worklight.

I am using AngujarJS as the framework along with HTML, CSS and Bootstrap.

As this being a SPA, we are using ngRoute/UI.Route (Need to decide on whether to continue with ngRoute or UI.Route) to route between pages.

While the app works fine on iOS, Android and BB, it does not render anything on Windows Phone 8 Hybrid App. Meaning, it is not able to pick the file when we say

```
templateUrl : 'views/Login.html'
```

One blog suggested that we will have to give absolute path in order to make it work like -

```
templateUrl : 'www/default/views/Login.html'
```

But this is not the correct solution. Is there any setting that we need to do in order to make it work on windows8 phones.

Thank You in Advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not convinced this has to do with AngularJS, but rather to plain JavaScript used in jQuery in conjunction with Windows Phone8, which is notorious to not work well when it comes to web-based multipage apps.

See the following questions for related issues:

1. [Using jquery mobile in IBM Worklight for WIndows Phone 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22502080/using-jquery-mobile-in-ibm-worklight-for-windows-phone-8)
2. [IBM Worklight v 5.0.6 - Can't navigate multipages on Windows Phone 7.5 environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17965560/ibm-worklight-v-5-0-6-cant-navigate-multipages-on-windows-phone-7-5-environme)
3. [IBM Worklight - $("#pagePort").load() not working in Windows Phone 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18491348/ibm-worklight-pageport-load-not-working-in-windows-phone-8)
4. [IBM Worklight 6.0 - WL.Client.reloadApp() not working in Windows Phone 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22792645/ibm-worklight-6-0-wl-client-reloadapp-not-working-in-windows-phone-8)

Comment: The problem with my approach was that for Win8 Phone we need to provide absolute path unlike other platforms.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was the path used.

Take a look at the multi-page sample project provided in the [IBM Worklight Getting Started webpage](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/mobile/worklight/getting-started.html). It contains special handling for WP8 which you may need to apply to your project.

[Building a multi-page application training module](http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/docs/v620/03_02_Building_a_multi_page_application.pdf)

[Multi-page sample project](http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/docs/v620/BuildingMultiPageApplicationProject.zip)

Note how the path is handled specifically for Windows Phone 8.

**common\main.js:**

```
var path = "";

function wlCommonInit(){
    // Special case for Windows Phone 8 only.
    if (WL.Client.getEnvironment() == WL.Environment.WINDOWS_PHONE_8) {
        path = "/www/default/";
    }    ...    ... }
```

**Conclusion: You need to account for the path for WP8 vs other platforms.**

Comment: Yes. We mention this in the training module and sample project indeed.